# How to GRANT specific permissions on current MySQL DB?

Tags: mysql, permissions

is it possible to not set DB name on which I'm granting permissions explicitly?

I want to do something like this:

```
USE db1;
GRANT SELECT ON * TO 'user'@'host';
```

Instead of this:

```
GRANT SELECT ON db1.* TO 'user'@'host';
```

Comment: According to the documentation it should do what you want. **If you use `ON *` syntax (rather than `ON *.*`) and you have selected a default database, privileges are assigned at the database level for the default database.**

Comment: See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/grant.html

Comment: @Barmar big thanks, don't know how I've missed that